# Ubuntu 20.04LTS - Jabra Talk 25 - earpiece works but mic doesn't

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, settings, headset, input

Jabra Talk 25 connects to Bluetooth ok. Ear piece works and can hear sound. However the microphone doesn't work. It can be selected in Bluetooth settings, but there is no sound.

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling with the settings I got it to work. In case someone else has this difficulty. I used these in Sound Settings

- Output Device: Headset-Jabra Talk 25
- Configuration: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)
- Input Device: Headset-Jabra Talk 25

It seems that the Configuration setting is key to allowing the microphone to work.

Comment: The above answer worked for me once, but now won't and only seems to work when connected over bluetooth. When connected with the dongle I can't see the speakers at all :-( I had similar issues with the Plantronics Voyager